# Getting Blank Screen while debugging in Android device in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, debugging

in flutter coming  blank screen while debugging on real android device(Android 13) its showing parameter format is not correct and while running web its working. I am using vs code and Android Studio

While connecting other phones also not working